# In Java, What can I use to convert the string "27/Jun/1991" to a date or timestamp?

Tags: java, date

In Java, What can I use to convert the string "27/Jun/1991" to a date or timestamp?

Comment: What language/framework?

Comment: Thanks for answer, i'm using java

Comment: Simply Use [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: @Luv, please take care with your edits. Code formatting is meant to be used for code, not merely to highlight portions of text.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java string to date conversion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216745/java-string-to-date-conversion)

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta I will take care of it. Thanks for your Advice **`:)`**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MMM/yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
Date date = sdf.parse("27/Jun/1991");
System.out.println(date);
```

output

```
Thu Jun 27 00:00:00 EEST 1991
```

Comment: Hi, output is: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "27/Jun/1991" at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:357) at svn_example1.SVN_Example1.main(SVN_Example1.java:661 
i'm using jdk 1.7

Comment: Well, I tested my code before posting, seems like you are running not my code

Comment: Thanks for answer, SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MMM/yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);

Locale.ENGLISH is important

Answer (score 0):

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MMM/yyyy");  
     Date date=null;;
    try {
        date = formatter.parse("27/Jun/1991");
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }  
     System.out.println("Date::" +date);  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MMM/yyyy");
    Date d = null;
    try {
        d = formatter.parse("27/Jun/1991");
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println(d);
```